# I am having trouble with an assignment in class, the objective is as follows:

Tags: python

Option 1 – Members Only
If you were going to create a club, what would it be and how could people join? Think about the membership requirements. Would members have to be between certain ages? Would they have to like certain things? Would they need certain skills? Because you are president of the club, you get to decide the criteria! (Just make sure the conditions are school appropriate.)
Follow these steps to begin your planning:

1. Create a club name and explain your club's purpose.
2. List the conditions (at least 3) to be a member of your club. Remember you have learned about if, if-else, elif, and logical operators (and, or, not), so you can test for just about anything.

here's what i have so far, what i want it for when i run the program, it prints sentences based off whether or not the conditions are true, but my problem is that its not printing when it should, what is wrong?

Here's the code:

```
def main():

    age = input("Would you be right for  our movie club? What is your age?")
    movies = input("How many movies have you watched?")

    if(age == 16 and movies == 10 ):
         print("Perfect")


main()
```

Comment: `input` returns a string, not an integer. `16` and `"16"` are two different values.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, input returns a string - you can trivially cast the input to an int as follows.  When checking for equality, a good thing to keep in mind when debugging is the use of `type(object)`.  Had you done this on the input variables, i.e. `age` you would see that `print(type(age))` returns `<type 'str'>`.

```
age = int(input("Would you be right for  our movie club? What is your age?"))
movies = int(input("How many movies have you watched?"))
if(age == 16 and movies == 10 ):
  print("Perfect")
```

Comment: we could even check if `int(...)` raises an error e.g. if someone writes "sixteen"

Comment: eh, this is a basic high-school class and i haven't learnt about that yet, so my teach wont take points of for that, all past assignment have been numerical

Comment: Nothing wrong with being ahead of the game... before you know it you may be behind ;)